# Delete item in mapped array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have an array and I'm mapping through it:

```
{items &&
      items.map((item) => (
        <div key={item}>
          {item} <button>Delete</button>
        </div>
      ))}
```

I'm keeping items in state hook - [items, setItems] = useState(itemsArray);
How do I remove the item at its specific index when I click that 'Delete' button?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Please [**search thoroughly**](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+%5Breactjs%5D+remove+item+from+array) before posting. More about searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: Thanks but the post you linked to has much more complicated syntax. Can't understand why this is considered a duplicate.

Comment: It's the same thing. An array, and a call to remove something from the array. The examples there are not over-complicated.

Comment: Yes but mine is the more general case so I don't see why this shouldn't coexist with the specific case. The examples are not over complicated because you probably already know how to code but for someone learning it makes a whole lot of difference.

Comment: SO's model is designed around **not** having a thousand copies of the same question, each with different answers. (Sadly, though, if you search, you'll find at least a dozen copies of "how do I remove an item from an array in React" anyway, this topic is **very** thoroughly covered here, because people think their question is special and there's an endless supply of people posting repeated questions.) Fundamentally, `setItems(items => items.filter((item, index) => index !== indexToRemove);` [Example search](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+%5Breactjs%5D+remove+item+by+index).

Comment: (Oops, missing `)` on that. :-) )